# How to implement Django users referred by other users relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, one-to-many

I want to implement a way to keep track of referrals in my django application.  I am using the default Users table.  A user can 'refer' multiple people, but a referred user can only be referred by one user.

I have tried adding this to my models.py but it is causing errors.

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referredBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this causes the below error:

```
ERRORS:
RateManager.Referral.referredBy: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Referral.referredBy' clashes with reverse query name for 'Referral.user'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Referral.referredBy' or 'Referral.user'.
```

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Did you try doing what the hint says?

Answer (score 0):

Simply omit the `referredBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` since the `OneToOneField` already references the `Users` table.

If for some reason you *need* to have both columns (I can't see why though), you can change your model's `related_name` attributes:

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referredBy = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='referredBy', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I can't keep track of who referred each user then.  When logged in as 'john' I want to be able to display all the users the 'john' has referred.

Comment: @NirmalMulji Did you try changing the `related_name` attribute?

Comment: this worked.  I am now able to query for all the users referred by another user using this: referrals = Referral.objects.filter(referredBy=user_id)

Comment: Can you explain why you need a 'related_name' attribute?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I think it has to do with the name Django picks for the foreign key relationships.  If you reference the same table twice, it will try to name both foreign keys the same name, which you can't do.

Comment: [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) is all I could find in the docs, which isn't that helpful.